# PDF Reader for MacOS with font size cutomization

Tags: pdf, font

Very often the font size in pdf files is too small. To read the document one has to continuously scroll and zoom the document, which I find really annoying, especially when several windows are opened. On the other hand in ebook readers (e.g. Kindle) there is the possibility to change the font size of a pdf file.

Do you know whether there is any pdf reader software for macOS that has this feature?

Comment: I've never seen any way to change pdf font size in Kindle other than zoom, unless you first convert it to some other format.

Comment: Only the .epub format has the feature to customize font size - so you may need to look for pdf to .epub converter if this is more useful to you

Comment: @TomGewecke Sorry I mean the Sony Reader, not Kindle. It has a function to change the font size.

Comment: @Yoan Convert it to epub first it is a good suggestion. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I found a description of the sony feature at   http://docs.esupport.sony.com/reader/PRST1/eng/contents/05/01/03/03.html

Answer (score 2):

Anyhow I found that using preview and the combination of commands cmd+ctrl+f the screen goes to two pages and it can be zoomed. This is comfortable enough for reading!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any app that will adjust just the font size. Adobe Acrobat Reader has multiple zoom settings which once set will stay at that level till changed. I often use this feature with settings like 125% or 150%. These setting are numerical in value instead on the common 'Zoom In' or 'Zoom Out' so its easy to reproduce. I think to change font size only one would have to convert PDF to a text document, adjust the font, and convert back to PDF. Not a cheap option but Acrobat Reader can do this for a price.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I don't think PDF works that way. While you can have text in a PDF, along with it you'll have the font & placement on the page. If you want to alter the representation on the page you really should do it in an editor not a viewer, where text & metadata are handled separately instead of being bound together.